# cron artisan laravel reg.ru

Tags: php, laravel, cron

Всех приветствую, никто не подскажет как добавить крон для проекта на laravel которых находится на виртуальном хостинге reg.ru. В документации описан путь к скрипту, но у меня по сути должен запускаться `php artisan shedule:run` а не сам путь к файлу.

Comment: Вроде оно [Running The Scheduler](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling#running-the-scheduler)

Comment: https://help.reg.ru/hc/ru/articles/4408046932369-%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA-CRON

Comment: там они могутчерез визуальный интерфейс добавляться

Comment: соответственно вам нужна будет команда `cd /var/www/project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1` , а время и периодичность выполнения нужно будет мышкой натыкать в форме

Comment: путь к папке с проектом тоже придется в панели управления смотреть

Comment: в крайнем случае к техподдержке можно обратиться

Comment: ну а если у Вас VPS и есть доступ по SSH, то подключайтесь по нему и делайте как в ответе на прошлый вопрос